# Error in llvm 'make'

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to install llvm-3.1 on my machine. I downloaded the source files and 
used these steps

```
cd build/
../llvm-src/configure
make
make check-all
```

I tried to work on examples in llvm-src/lib/Analysis as mentioned 
http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html

A 'gmake' to compile custom .cpp files in this dir gives this error

```
Makefile.config:227: *** missing separator.
```

A typical error is usually related to spacing issues in the make file. But this is the Makefile that is already present. How do I rectify this.

Thanks